# Does voting anomaly detect this?

Tags: support, voting-anomaly-detection

I'm having all my question downvoted regularly in orders they appear in my profile. Interesting is that it's only done at a pace of 3 a day.

Is it some kind of attempt to circumvent anomalous voting pattern detection?

**Update:**

I've just looked at older history of my reputation, and apparently the anomalous voting pattern detection does detect that and does take care of that. It does however take a few days.

Comment: Is this on SO or MSO? Because in the latter case, users would just disagree with you a lot

Comment: @Ivo if you know (and can comment on it), does the voting detection stuff not run on MSO?

Comment: I do think it runs, just that people vote too much that it won't get triggered against a single user.

Comment: @Ivo: actually it started on SU, then happened on MSO. Yes, people do disagree with me a lot, but in that case someone just down-voted my 3 top up-voted questions in rapid succession, so I'm quite sure that's it's retaliatory voting.

Comment: I find it more likely people discussed your answer and all decided to show you how they disagree. I don't see any anomalies in the voting, so I would just suggest proposing better ideas :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they keep the details of that closed off so people can't do things like this to circumvent it. If the downvotes aren't cleaned up automatically within a few days, I'd flag one of your posts with a note to the moderators or send a note to the support email at the bottom of the page with your suspicions.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like someone who is aware of the voting pattern feature and is trying to get around it.  Flag one of your downvoted posts for moderator review and have them look at it.  History has shown that the specific items in the voting anomaly algorithm are pretty tight under wraps and answering this would certainly reveal a key aspect of it.